# Session in rails and security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, session

I have a really special login feature in my app, so instead of plugins I use my own code.

In my controller I have something like

```
def login
  ...
  session[:customer_id] = id
end
```

I use CookieStore (as default). So is it secure? What if somebody edit cookies? Can he impersonates somebody with another id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A message digest is included with the cookie to ensure data integrity: a user cannot alter his user_id without knowing the secret key included in the hash. New apps are generated with a pregenerated secret in config/environment.rb. Set your own for old apps you‘re upgrading.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Session/CookieStore.html. Please also pay attention to this sentence :

> If you have more than 4K of session data or **don‘t want your data to be visible to the user**, pick another session store.

In your situation, it certainly doesn't matter and you can use CookieStore without fear.